# How to use \displaybreak?

Tags: equations, page-breaking, amsmath

I have a very long equation

```
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{aligned}
    multiple line equation...
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

But just using the above code causes the whole equation to start from a new page leaving behind a third of previous page empty.
Where should i put the \displaybreak command to ensure that the page breaks occurs conveniently in between the equation. 
I tried using it in the following manner but it doesn't help.

```
\begingroup
\allowdisplaybreak
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{aligned}
    multiple line equation...
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
 \endgroup
```

Comment: The point is that, aligned environment wraps its contents inside an unbreakable box. So, these commands (both `\displaybreak` and `\allowdisplaybreaks`) do not have any effect. You may want to look at http://texdoc.net/pkg/amsldoc, towards the end of page 6.

Comment: You have to use `align*` for `\displaybreak` to work.

Comment: @egreg i tried using `\begin{align*}` instead of `\begin{aligned}`. But i still get the following error `! Undefined control sequence. \allowdisplaybreak` and `! Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures;(amsmath) trying to recover with 'aligned'`

Comment: It's `\allowdisplaybreaks`.

Comment: As @egreg says, it's `\allowdisplaybreaks` and should go after you include `amsmath`

Answer (score 12):

The point is that, aligned environment wraps its contents inside an unbreakable box. So, these commands (that is, both `\displaybreak` and `\allowdisplaybreaks`) do not have any effect.

This is true of `split`, `gathered` and `alignedat` environments too.

So, to get the line break to work, you might consider using `align*`, as suggested by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg).

You might want to refer to [`amsldoc`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf), towards the end of page 6 for these comments. I'd also like to draw your attention to the section 3 of this document for discussions regarding display math.

---

<sub>By the way, please note that, you have `s` missing in `\allowdisplaybreaks`.</sub>