# Allow page breaks in a gather environment with a nested align

Tags: align, amsmath, displaystyle, displaybreak

I have two consecutive lists of equations, the second of which is quite long (16 lines with no reasonable way to shorten it apparent). Because the center alignment of `gather` looks ugly in this case, I've nested an align environment in order to align the various equations in a sensible way.

Unfortunately, the second list is long enough that I would like to allow it to break over two pages to avoid the massive white space that results when the entire list floats to the next page. I'd like to let TeX handle it automatically rather than forcing the break with `\displaybreak`.

The super simplified MWE (without alignment characters since only the length of the environment, and not the specific alignment, seems to matter):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc} % Needed to avoid strange behavior of the footnote
\linespread{1.55}
\begin{document}

Here is my first gather with nested align
\begin{gather}
    \begin{align}
    1\\
    2\\
    3\\
    4\\
    5\\
    6\\
    7\footnotemark
    \end{align}
\end{gather}
\footnotetext{Footnote text.} 

Here is my second gather with nested align:
\begin{gather}
    \begin{align}
        1\\
        2\\
        3\\
        4\\
        5\\
        6\\
        7\\
        8\\
        9\\
        10\\
        11\\
        12\\
        13\\
        14\\
        15\\
        16
    \end{align}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

Now, there's at least one problem with this attempt that I'm aware of:

I shouldn't use `align`: as explained in [this answer to "How to use \displaybreak"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112482/17835) `align` environments are unbreakable and so `\allowdisplaybreaks` and `\displaybreak` have no effect. The suggestion there is to use `align*`.

Unfortunately, the same problem arises with a simple substitution of `align*` for `align` in the preceding MWE (also it's quite annoying to not have automatic numbering).

How can I achieve an aligned list of numbered equations (that are easy to cross-reference and, if possible, automatically tagged) that will break across pages when length and context requires?

**Edit 1**

As [juanuni](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14423/juanuni) points out in the comments, the `gather` environment is unnecessary here. The reason it is there is somewhat idiosyncratic. In the document this problem arose in I have custom `gather` and `equation` environments with distinct counters and tag formats. Being a bit lazy, I just used the custom gather environment to pass the relevant counter (not `equation`'s counter) and tag format to the nested align.

**Edit 2** (Now with puzzlement!)

Well, a combination of shame and insomnia prompted me to stop being lazy and just create the custom `align` environment. Interestingly, when I use my custom `align` without nesting it in the custom `gather`, I get the desired result: the long `align` environment breaks across the page.

But this confuses me. My custom `align` (along with the new counter) is defined as follows:

```
\newcounter{defcounter}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{defalign}{%
  \let\c@equation\c@defcounter% switches to defcounter
  \renewcommand\theequation{D.\arabic{equation}}
  \align}
  {\endalign}
\makeatother
```

But the [the answer linked above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112338/how-to-use-displaybreak/112482#112482) suggests that what I just did shouldn't work. Why does it?

Comment: Without `gather` environment you can obtain the same result. From the other hand, I don't know what equations have you, but maybe you could decrease the vertical space between equations making `\\[0.5cm]` (or what you want) instead just \\, to adjust the vertical space ...

Comment: @juanuni Good call with `gather` being unnecessary. I was using a modified gather environment (with a counter distinct from `equation`'s) in the non-MWE, but has no effect on the problematic behavior here. Essentially, I was just using the `gather` to provide the relevant counter (not `equation`'s counter) for the nested `align`. Probably a less hack-ish way to do it, but I was lazy. I'll mention this in the question since the fact that these environments are nested _might_ be relevant to page breaking behavior in the non-MWE (though I really don't know) and they'll be nested there.

Comment: :O I understand.

Comment: @Dennis Based on your comment, this is an XY question: you think that abusing `gather` has solved your problem with the counter, but, as you clearly see, it hasn't. So, please, accept the given answer and ask a new question stating your *real* problem, that is, changing the counter used by `align` (which is surely solvable without abusing `gather`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\allowdisplaybreaks` doesn't work simply because you are nesting an `align` inside a `gather` environment. This causes the `align` to be wrapped in an unbreakable box. The solution is obvious: remove the `gather` environment, which is unneeded.

But the `align` itself isn't generally wrapped in an unbreakable box. This is **always** true for the following `amsmath`'s environments:

- `split`
- `aligned`
- `gathered`
- `alignedat`

Note that the first three are meant to be used inside another math environment like `equation`.

In regards of your latest question, the answer you refer to states that **`aligned` inside `equation*`** is unbreakable and the suggestion is to use `align*` instead. Nowhere is stated that `align` is unbreakable.